# Pass Null Parameter for UniqueIdentfier Datatype in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Declare @ID uniqueidentifier =Null

select * from Emp where EmpID=@ID
```

Above query giving no results.

Comment: `=NULL` does not work. SQL syntax is: `WHERE` x `IS NULL`

Comment: Where IS @ID giving error

Comment: I need to pass parameter value as null in query

Comment: select * from Emp where EmpID=@ID or (EmpID IS NULL and @ID IS NULL)

Comment: [Understanding NULL](https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/sql-prompt/the-null-mistake-and-other-sql-null-heresies) is pretty darn important.

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` is not a value, is a state, so you can't test for something equals to `NULL` using standard operators.

All expression in which is involved a `NULL` will result in `NULL`

```
DECLARE @I INT = NULL
DECLARE @A VARCHAR(20) = NULL

'Hello ' + @A + 'World' = NULL
127 * 54 - (32 / @i) = NULL
```

So your query `select * from Emp where EmpID=@ID` will give no results when `@ID` is null

You need to use the special operator `IS NULL` to test for your parameter (see @Sergey comment)

```
select * 
from Emp 
where EmpID=@ID  /* this will catch rows when @ID is not NULL */
or (EmpID IS NULL and @ID IS NULL) /* this will catch rows when @ID is NULL */
```

Answer (score -1):

Handle it using the ternery operator like this

```
Declare @ID nvarchar(50);
select * from Emp where EmpID=@ID is null?0:@ID;
```

Comment: The words is "ternary", SQL Server doesn't have one, it does have `CASE` though, but you can't return a boolean out of it